# react function state is not defined no-undef

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I create this function startStop for such button to start and pause a timer. The error is "Line 108:22:  'sessionLength' is not defined  no-undef" (line 108 is the last "this.setState()" in this code block) does it have to do anything with binding? what's wrong?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    breakLength: 5,
    sessionLength: 25,
    timerState: "paused",
  }

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.startStop = this.startStop.bind(this)
  }

startStop() { 

    if (this.state.timerState === "paused") {
      this.setState({
        timerState: setInterval(() => decrement(), 1000)
      }, function () {console.log(this.state.timerState)})

    }
    
    else if (this.state.timerState !== "paused") {
      console.log(this.state.timerState)
      clearInterval(this.state.timerState)
      this.setState({
        timerState: "paused"
      }, function () {console.log(this.state.timerState)})
    }

    this.setState({
      sessionLength: sessionLength - remaining
    }, function () {console.log(this.state.sessionLength)})

  }
```

Answer (score 1):

`sessionLength` is a member of `this.state`, so to access it you would need to use `this.state.sessionLength`.

```
    this.setState({
      sessionLength: this.state.sessionLength - remaining
    }
```

Comment: Thank you. this works! any reason why we don't need to do "this.state.sessionLength:" ?

Comment: Yeah so basically the object passed to `this.setState()` is of the form `{ somePropertyName: someValue }`. The name of the piece of state you want to update is "sessionLength", and we don't use "this.state.sessionLength:" as the name because its value is a number.

Comment: You maybe be wondering  _"how does React know to update "sessionLength" at `this.state.sessionLength`?"_. It's because [React merges the state update](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-are-merged) from the argument in `this.setState({ ... })` and your existing state in `this.state` under the hood.

Comment: Makes a lot of sense now. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you should declare **state** inside the **constructor**

You try:

```
    constructor(props) {
     super(props)
     this.state = {
        breakLength: 5,
        sessionLength: 25,
        timerState: "paused",
     }
     this.startStop = this.startStop.bind(this)
    }
```

Comment: I added it to constructor but still have to use this.state.sessionLength. Any reason to put it in constructor?